# Shortcode function not showing up on mobile browser

Tags: plugins, shortcode, mobile, responsive

I recently received an email from Google Search Console saying that I have new Mobile Usability issues on my site.

I have a shortcode on a page that allows users to sign in and fill in a form and upload information.

The shortcode function works on desktop but no longer works on mobile. Is there anyway to make it responsive again? 
I suspect the problem is having updated Wordpress to the latest version.

Comment: A little more info might be needed - got a URL?

Comment: Hi Jeff - the URL for my site is: https://findyourhustle.co.uk, and the shortcode is on the "candidate" page

Comment: Are the two issues related, the mobile usability and shortcode issues? When you say it's "not working", do you mean that the shortcode doesn't function at all, or just that it causes the mobile usability issues? As far as I can tell the form is working fine.

Comment: Yeah the form is fine, it's your Elementor hidden on mobile rule that's causing the link to not appear on smaller devices.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you!! It was the Elementor hidden on mobile rule. Thanks for taking the time to check it out. Blessings @JeffW and JacobPeattie